# Wrap routes inside a container in Ember 2

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember route/templates with some content inside. I want to show this content in two different ways in my app. The first way is with a `Container` that wrap it with additional functionalities, the second way is just to show the content of the route.

```
+-Container---+
|             | 
+-Content-----+   +-Content---+
||           ||   |           |
||           ||   |           |
|-------------|   +-----------+
+-------------+
```

What is the correct way to do it using Ember 2? Query params? Nested routes?

Answer (score 0):

This highly depends on whats the decision making thing to show the container or not. You have a few options here.

First its probably not a bad idea to put both, the container and the content into a component. So now you can so either this:

```
{{#my-container}}
  {{my-content model=model}}
{{/my-container}}
```

or just this:

```
{{my-content model=model}}
```

now you can just separate with a simple `{{#if}}` statement which one you wanna render. You can do this based on a query param, or you could have two routes where one has the upper and one the lower code snipped. However this means you have to duplicate the model hook.

Both is a valid solution! The better depends on why you want to have theese two views, and all the surrounding things.